# best way to transfer data from flask to d3

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, flask, routes

I have csv tables, processed in Pandas, that I would like to serve from Flask to the browser so that I can use d3 to display the information. How do I transfer the data from Flask to the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the to_csv method of the Pandas dataframe, and return that from your flask server:

```
# app.py
@app.route('/my/data/entpoint')
def get_d3_data():
    df = pandas.DataFrame(...) # Constructed however you need it
    return df.to_csv()
```

Then on the front end, direct d3.tsv to your endpoint above:

```
<!-- page.html -->
<script>
d3.tsv("/my/data/endpoint", function(data) {
  console.log(data); // Do something with data
});
</script>
```

Comment: in the first snippet i'm seeing pands,to_csv while in the second one i'm seeing d3.tsv