# Trying to pass csv from pandas to d3.js using flask

Tags: csv, pandas, d3.js, flask

Below is my flask code. I am connecting to a sqlite database , getting some data and making a pandas dataframe and converting it to **CSV** and trying to pass it to d3.js

```
 import sqlite3
 import pandas as pd
 from flask import *
 app = Flask(__name__)
 @app.route("/new_graph",methods = ['GET','POST'])
 def new_graph():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('recruit.db')
    query = "select * from customers"
    //bunch of dataframe calculations using pandas

    data = final_df.to_csv(sep=',')
    print (data)
    return render_template('new_display.html',data=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(app.run( port=8069),debug=True)
```

Also tried,

```
@app.route("/new_graph",methods = ['GET','POST'])
def new_graph():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        connection = sqlite3.connect('recruit.db')
        query = "select * from customers"
    //bunch of dataframe calculations using pandas

        data = final_df.to_csv(sep=',')
        return data
    return render_template('new_display.html')
```

Below is my **html**:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>


d3.csv("/new_graph", function(data) {  //recommended way of passing csv 
  console.log(data[0]);
});

 </script>
</body>
```

When I run this, it runs fine and the csv gets printed:

```
 127.0.0.1 - - [02/May/2017 17:52:12] "GET /new_graph HTTP/1.1" 200 -
,Home_Owners,Home_renters,Ethinicity
0,1229,24,Asian
1,9856,584,Black
2,793,11,Chinese
3,8681,351,Hispanic
4,256,6,American Indian
5,141,5,Japanese
6,23855,449,Other
7,4,0,Portuguese
8,39284,611,White

127.0.0.1 - - [02/May/2017 17:52:17] "GET /new_graph HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But **console.log** prints a weird output:

```
  Object {<!DOCTYPE html>: ""}
```

Unable to figure out , where I am going wrong.

Comment: Why are you logging just `data[0]`?  What happens if you log `data`?

Comment: Solution looks simpler than your own attempts, according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881571/best-way-to-transfer-data-from-flask-to-d3

Answer (score 0):

You pass the csv data to the template file. The endpoint `new_graph` return a html instead of the csv data you want. You can return the csv data directly.

Comment: Please see the edited code reflecting the new approach of returning data directly.

Comment: Are you sure the `d3.csv` send the `POST` request instead of `GET`?

Comment: According to their documentation here: https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#csv, the callback triggers a `GET` request.